# Comic book series - three protagonists are a young boy, a young girl, and a young wizard

Tags: story-identification, comics

Probably 15-20 years ago, my oldest brother gave me a handful of graphic novels in a series (I don't know if they were originally released as comic books, or were directly put in books). It was set in a fantasy world, about medieval levels of tech, with magic. The first main character we're introduced to is a red or brown haired boy, probably young teen at most, caucasian skin. I think he's introduced escaping from a sailing ship where he was basically an indentured servant as the cabin boy. He identifies as a hero or maybe as a great thief. Then, there's a dark-haired girl (a princess?), also pale-skinned, who he runs into, and I think perhaps rescues her (although she's competent in her own right, and a bit of a tomboy) during a palace coup? The third person is a wizard, maybe early 20s. He's supposed to be extremely powerful in magic, but seldom demonstrates those skills. I think he's one of the teachers to the girl, maybe from his house out in the woods? I remember one of his demonstrations of skill involved vanishing something from a washtub. I think his name may have started with a Q, maybe Quentin? Their primary antagonist is a dark-haired woman (maybe 20s to 30s) who wields a dark sword, usually one-handed.

I think I had 3-4 volumes, and over the course of events, we learn that the woman with the sword is not as villainous as initially portrayed, and actually may be a future version of the young girl. Similarly, I remember it as being implied that Quentin is the future version of the young boy, although I don't recall exactly how it all worked out. I think there were some other monstrous races in the world, although I don't recall many "humanoid fantasty races" like elves, dwarves, etc. The art style was simple, non-realistic. People were fairly normal proportions, not exaggerated. My memories have the comic in color, although I might be misremembering that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty sure that's Thieves & Kings [official site](http://iboxpublishing.com/index.php)

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thieves_and_Kings)

> **Rubel (pronounced "rue-bell")**
> Thieves & Kings' protagonist, Rubel is a combination of hero and everyman. The story opens with Rubel as a boy of 14, (he ages as the story progresses) returning home from an apprenticeship at sea. Rubel was born in the "Sleeping Wood," a magical forest that borders Highborn, and was raised by his grandfather, with additional influence from Quinton the wizard and some local townspeople. At a very young age (recounted in the book as a flashback) Rubel declared himself to be a "thief," a vocation in Oceansend that means a lot more than just one-who-steals, and seems to be closer to paladin. Rubel has proven himself to be capable of very decisive action, while maintaining an innocent, almost naive, view of the world.
>
> **Heath Wingwhit**
> Heath is a few years younger than Rubel. She enters the story as a young orphaned girl living in the small village of Millbrook, in the past. She apprentices herself to the wizard Quinton, despite the fact that most in Millbrook believe him to be a fraud. She eventually travels to Highborn, where she meets Rubel and becomes a powerful sorceress in her own right.
>
> **Quinton Zempfester (a.k.a. Kaluvinar)**
> Quinton is a wizard. He is immortal, and seems to be very adept at planning for events many years in advance. While he frequently appears to be scatter-brained and even foolish, he seems to have the respect of many of the mystical and powerful beings in Oceansend. Quinton very rarely displays any magical abilities directly

Comment: And, now that you describe it, I can find it on my bookshelf. Thank you.

Comment: One of my favourite comics. The latest ongoing installment of *Thieves & Kings*, as well as two other comics updating intermittently, can be read on Mark Oakley's webpage http://iboxpublishing.com/index.php